# Proving the tail end of a convergent sequence equals zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The main question is: prove $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}|$ is less that or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|A_{n}|$

(given that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ converges absolutely).

I have got to the stage in my proof where I need to prove that the tail end of a series converges, e.g.:
prove ∑An from some value of n, (N) each n > or equal to N is equal to zero. Is there a way of writing this algebraically or does a written explanation suffice?

Comment: By the way, if you plan to ask more questions here, learn how to write in $\Latex$.

Comment: And what comes after your "e.g." is wrong: what you have to prove is that that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}^\infty A_m=0\;$$  not that the sum *equals zero* ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, since the series converges, we can put

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\color{red}{S_N}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^NA_n}$$

and thus

$$\sum_{n=m}^\infty A_n=S-S_{m-1}\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} \lim_{m\to\infty} {\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}{A_n}} = \lim_{m \to \infty}{S} - \lim_{m \to \infty}{S_{m-1}} = S-S=0$$

Comment: If $ \sum A_{n}=S $, is it okay to write that for all $ m $, $$ S=S_{m}+T_{m+1}? $$ where $ S_{m}=A_1+\dots+A_{m} $ and $ T_{m+1}=A_{m+1}+A_{m+2}+\cdots $. I don't know if I am being pedantic here or really missing something!

Comment: @SubhajitPaul It'd be fine as long as it is clearly understood that $\;A_n+T_{m+1}\;$ is taking *THE LIMIT* of those terms, otherwise it'd be like writing that $$0=a_n+T_{n+1}\;,\;\;a_n=1+\frac12+\ldots+\frac1n\;,\;\;T_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}+\ldots$$ which of course makes no sense without taking the limit...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Triangular inequality.

If this does not help, I will complete the answer.